# How can I use shortcut keys in a ReactJS modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, redux

I am trying to create a POS application where a single product can have multiple prices. So if the product has multiple prices then I am displaying a modal but the issue is that I have integrated shortcuts in that modal but when the modal gets opened for the first time I want to focus on the first table row. How can I do that?

[image]

here is my code

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const handleShortCut = (e) => {
      const totalButtons = buttonsRef.current.length;

      if (e.altKey && e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
        setFocusedIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex - 1 + totalButtons) % totalButtons);
      } else if (e.altKey && e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
        setFocusedIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % totalButtons);
        if (focusedIndex === totalButtons - 1) {
          setFocusedIndex(0); // Wrap around to the first element
        }
      } else if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        // Trigger a click event on the focused button
        const focusedButton = buttonsRef.current[focusedIndex];
        if (focusedButton) {
          focusedButton.click();
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleShortCut);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleShortCut);
    };
  }, [focusedIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    buttonsRef.current[focusedIndex]?.focus();
    buttonsRef.current.forEach((button, index) => {
      if (index === focusedIndex) {
        button.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)';
      } else {
        button.style.backgroundColor = ''; 
      }
    });
  }, [focusedIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2);
    if (focusedIndex === 0 || focusedIndex == null) {
      console.log(1);
      buttonsRef.current[0]?.focus();
      buttonsRef.current.forEach((button, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
          button.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)';
        } else {
          button.style.backgroundColor = '';
        }
      });
    }
  }, [focusedIndex]);
```

**TABLE CODE**

```
 <tbody>
              {multiplePrices.map((price, index) => (
                <tr key={Math.random(Math.random() * Math.random())}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setProductIntoTheCart(price);
                    setmodal_standard(!modal_standard)
                    setFocusedIndex(null)
                  }}
                  ref={(el) => (buttonsRef.current[index] = el)}
                >
                  <td>{index + 1}</td>
                  <td>&#8377; {price.price_mrp}</td>
                  <td>&#8377; {price.price_purchase}</td>
                  <td>&#8377; {price.price_sales}</td>
                  <td>&#8377; {price.price_online}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
```